# Stream/Query transaction price history of an asset

Tags: cardano-db-sync, blockfrost

Is it possible to get the transaction incl. price history of an asset e.g. ([SundaeSwap](https://cardanoscan.io/token/9a9693a9a37912a5097918f97918d15240c92ab729a0b7c4aa144d7753554e444145)) using blockfrost or cardano-db-sync?

If yes, is it also possible to stream this value from block to block?

Answer (score 0):

No, as this information is not directly on-chain.